# Free database for small datawarehouse

Tags: database, open-source, data-warehouse

Which free database would you use for a relatively small datawarehouse system?

Are there any 'special' databases e.g. multidimensional databases freely available?

Which of the free relational databases is best suited for the job?

By datawarehouse system I mean a system that will receive some inserts, few updates, next to no deletes and plenty of complex selects. Structured in star schemas (if the database is relational).

By small I mean about 100.000 records in the main fact table, maybe 10 dimensions, the largest containing 5.000 records.

Be free I mean free of charge of internal commercial use.

Edit: Since so far I mostly only got a list of free databases, let me specify some features that would be interesting / needed:

- outer joins (must)
- inlineviews / subselects (almost must)
- materialized views (nice)
- smart query optimizer (the smarter the better)
- support for dimensions, roll up, cube queries (nice)
- analytic functions (that's the name in oracle, don't know how they are named in other databases)(nice)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have had very good results with [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). It's free, open source, runs on all major platforms and has support for all important database functions.
There are excellent tools available to manage the databases, like IB-Expert which has a free (limited, but good enough) version.

Answer (score 2):

- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)
- [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/)
- [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)

Comment: so which one would you recommend?

Comment: If you need a single user to access at once = SQLITE
If you need many users updating data = MySQL/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

If the total amount of data < 4 gigabyte you can use Oracle XE.

Edit: Jens Schauder came with new 'demands'. I believe that ProgeSQL, MySQL and SQLite don't support analytics.

Comment: true, but I don't like the fixed limit. It would force use to migrate at a fixed point, or the whole thing would come to a full stop.

Comment: Late add:  Oracle 11 G limit is now 11 GB

Answer (score 1):

What about SQL Server Express?

Comment: Has it any limitations, like maximum users, memory, db file size or similiar?

Comment: Feature compare to Compact: http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/8/8/e8859616-e95d-41fe-9f81-ff88388d772b/SQLServer%202008CompareComapctExpress.pdf. See also http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express.aspx

Answer (score -1):

If the purpose of the data warehouse is not to improve the finances of the company in some way then you should save the effort and forget about wasting your time.

If the data warehouse is actually going to make money for the company in some way then it spending a few bucks on a real system is probably not unreasonable.

Comment: Sorry, but this is completly backwards. The question is not if I/we save/earn some money by implementing the datawarehouse. The question is: do we save/earn more money by using an expensive db compared to a cheap/free one. You can guess the answer we came up with from my original question.

Comment: By the way: Most licensing schemes don't really result in a 'few bucks'

Comment: A few thousand bucks then, for Oracle SE or SE1 where you get star query optimisation? What kind of pathetic ROI would a data warehouse have to have to not be able to justify that? You're already in the hole for hardware, ETL coding and support.

Comment: Btw, you didn't ask for cheap/free - you asked for free. Free data warehousing software is just as available as free staff to support it.