# Database stored on a shared drive

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have to make a database for 250 students which will have around 100-200 columns. Now its not possible to install MYSQL or anything like that on the server.All we can get is a shared folder on the server. The client side can have anything installed. There will be around 5-10 clients who will add,edit or delete the records. I though about SQLite as an option. Is there any security issues with it???

I need a database to be accessed by a 5 to 10 clients. We do not have a full server per se but rather a shared folder on a server. We therefore cannot install any server-side software, only client-side.

Comment: What application you will be using to access that database? Also note that mySQL is free, and MS SQL and ms access are not.

Comment: No need to close this question. I think the text just needs to be clearer...

Comment: i will be using vb.net or php. whichever is handy. But the thing to note is that the softwares cannot be installed on the server

Comment: It's unusual that such a table would contain 100-200 columns. Perhaps a better design is required.

Comment: http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

I would use SQLite. You could also use MS Access but consider that problems with old MS Access databases are common in companies where Access where used on the late nineties.

Comment: -1 "You could also use MS Access but I would not recoment it since you are dependand of Microsoft decissions." silly comment that detracts from the answer. SQLite is a very valid suggestion though.

Comment: Just shorten your answer to recommending SQLite because it fits the exact needs of the question

Comment: So using SQL means that i need not install anything on the server.Just store the files on the server's shared folder and access it using SQL on the client's side??...If so are there any problems with updating the database when clients modify the data??

Comment: @NicholasKing I have met real problems with MS Access because new versions are not able to open old files. I think backward compatibility is an important non-functional requirement to consider when you are choosing a technology.

Comment: @nute agreed the microsoft dig is invalid as it is applicable to EVERY piece of software you use whether it be sqlite, oracle, mssql etc. You will always be at the behest of some company, organisation or disperate group

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo thats not unique to MS though that is any software.

Comment: @user1747428 Problems with concurrency are handled using file locking. Check this out for more details: http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html

Comment: @user1747428 careful he wrote SQLite not just SQL. SQLite is just one implementation of SQL that is simply stored as a file - therefore it cna help in your case.

Comment: @user1747428 I think this could be, in short, what you are looking for: http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/  You simply need to install this on your own computer instead of the server, and point it to a remote file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following questions here

- https://superuser.com/questions/111798/small-database-recommendation-free
- [Free database for small datawarehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645729/free-database-for-small-datawarehouse)

You will find enough information to get you started.

Else look at these

1. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)
2. [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)